# WPF DataGrid Progressbar with Text

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, progress-bar

I have looked around to see a solution to my problem but I believe a lot of the solutions available are long winded for the problem.

Basically I have a Progressbar inside a Datagrid cell that is working as it should. However, I now want to put text inside the Progressbar to display the actually percentage. 
How is this done?

My code thus far

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Percentage Downloaded" Width="5*">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                 <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=PercentageDownloaded, Mode=OneWay}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" />
              </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

To show effort on my behalf, I have tried using the tag property within the progress bar and using a textblock which both have failed.

Many thanks

*** Solution ***

The solution provided by GiangregorioC works, as I didn't realise you can put  tag within a DataGridCellTemplate!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put the progress bar and the textblock inside a grid, something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

The textblock will appear hover the progressbar.

Comment: Actually I just saw that code around 5 secs ago, however can you put <grid> inside a DataGridCellTemplate? probably faster if I just try...

Comment: Yes you can add a Grid in your DataTemplate.